# Why library jar writes logs in tomcat catalina.out?

Tags: tomcat, logging

I have developed an application that used 3-rd party library jars. After deploying on tomcat I found that these libraries writes in catalina.out. I don't have access to they code.

Does it possible redirect they log to separate file or don't allow write to catalina.out ?
Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the libraries and if they use a configurable logging library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to change logging.properties to suppress these log messages by their logger names. To actually modify the code would involve ASM or some other really tricky stuff.